# NX Angular project build failed after upgrading to Webpack 5.79.0

Tags: angular, webpack, nrwl-nx

My nx monorepo angular project builds correctly with version 5.78.0 but got the following errors after upgrading to 5.79.0

nx: 15.9.2
angular: 15.2.6

```
 Error: Module parse failed: parser.destructuringAssignmentPropertiesFor is not a function
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
TypeError: parser.destructuringAssignmentPropertiesFor is not a function
```

Expect the project to build correctly

Comment: Are you using nx migrate?

Comment: No, I updated it manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like an [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/16981) with changes in webpack 5.79 if you are using a custom webpack config with the `DefinePlugin`.

I think it happens because there are multiple conflicting versions of webpack installed in node modules; the `DefinePlugin` is loaded from the newer version of webpack in node modules, but `webpack` itself is loaded from the Angular build tools version of wepback, which is [older](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/15.2.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/package.json#L64).

You can see this if you run `npm ls webpack` in your project folder:

```bash
> npm ls webpack

+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.5
| +-- @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1502.5
| | `-- webpack@5.79.0 deduped
...
| `-- webpack@5.76.1
```

You can downgrade to an earlier version of webpack as a workaround:

```bash
npm i -D webpack@~5.78.0
```

Alternatively you can run `npm dedupe`, which will result in only webpack v5.76.1 being installed, but this also dedupes other node modules which might not be desirable.

Comment: Brilliant catch! My version happened to be exactly 5.79.0 after reinstalling a project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with JHipster v7.9.3 after generating code using my blueprint.  The below worked for me, based on the above answer:
I edited the blueprint client folder's `package.json.ejs`, per below:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    <%_
      // Saathratri Modification:
    _%>
    "webpack": "<%= dependabotPackageJson.devDependencies['webpack'] %>",
    <%_ 
      // Saathratri Modification end.
    _%>
    ...
  }
```

and commented out:

```
  <%_
  // Saathratri Modification:
  // "overrides": {
  //  "webpack": " dependabotPackageJson.devDependencies['webpack']"
  //},
  _%>
```

Now I get the following after running `npm ls webpack` from within my generated project's directory:

```
saathratri-app-holder@ /Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder
└─┬ organizationsservice@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> ./organizationsservice
  ├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.1
  │ ├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1402.1
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ @ngtools/webpack@14.2.1
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ babel-loader@8.2.5
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ css-loader@6.7.1
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ less-loader@11.0.0
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@2.6.1
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ postcss-loader@7.0.1
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ sass-loader@13.0.2
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ source-map-loader@4.0.0
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ stylus-loader@7.0.0
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@4.10.0
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ ├─┬ webpack-subresource-integrity@5.1.0
  │ │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  ├─┬ browser-sync-webpack-plugin@2.3.0
  │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@11.0.0
  │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  ├─┬ eslint-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
  │ └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
  └─┬ webpack@5.74.0
    └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.7
      └── webpack@5.74.0 deduped
```

Notice the correct Webpack version is being used - the one that should be used according to JHipster v7.9.3; the correct version of Webpack is 5.74.0 for JHipster v7.9.3.

All references to webpack@5.79.0 from the `npm ls webpack` command were no longer there and the `parser.destructuringAssignmentPropertiesFor is not a function` error went away when running `./mvnw clean package` or `./mvnw spring-boot:run` from the generated project's directory.